# Can somebody help to model this function (polynomial function) in SMT solver Z3?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

F(x1) > a;

F(x2) < b;

∀t, F'(x) >= 0 (derivative) ;

F(x) = ∑ ci*x^i; (i∈[0,n] ; c is a constant)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguous, and stack-overflow works the best if you show what you tried and what problems you ran into.

Nevertheless, here's how one can code your problem for a specific function `F = 2x^3 + 3x + 4`, using the Python interface to z3:

```py
from z3 import *

# Represent F as a function. Here we have 2x^3 + 3x + 4
def F(x):
  return 2*x*x*x + 3*x + 4

# Similarly, derivative of F: 6x^2 + 3
def dF(x):
  return 6*x*x + 3

x1, x2, a, b = Ints('x1 x2 a b')
s = Solver()

s.add(F(x1) > a)
s.add(F(x2) < b)

t = Int('t')
s.add(ForAll([t], dF(t) >= 0))

r = s.check()
if r == sat:
    print s.model()
else:
    print ("Solver said: %s" % r)
```

Note that I translated your `∀t, F'(x) >= 0` condition as `∀t. F'(t) >= 0`. I assume you had a typo there in the bound variable.

When I run this, I get:

```
[x1 = 0, x2 = 0, b = 5, a = 3]
```

This method can be generalized to arbitrary polynomials with constant coefficients in the obvious way, but that's mostly about programming and not z3. (Note that doing so in SMTLib is much harder. This is where the facilities of host languages like Python and others come into play.)

Note that this problem is essentially non-linear. (Variables are being multiplied with variables.) So, SMT solvers may not be the best choice here, as they don't deal all that well with non-linear operations. But you can deal with those problems as they arise later on. Hope this gets you started!